# What does it mean to "fit" something using least squares?

Tags: regression, least-squares

Let's say that I have the linear combinations

$$Z_m = \sum_{j = 1}^p \phi_{jm} X_j$$

for some constants $\phi_{1m}, \phi_{2m}, \dots, \phi_{pm}$, $m = 1, \dots, M$. It is then said that we can "fit" the linear regression model

$$y_i = \theta_0 + \sum_{m = 1}^M \theta_m z_{im} + \epsilon_i, \ \ \ i = 1, \dots, n,$$

using least squares.

Although I am not experienced in statistics, I do know what regression and least squares are (from a mathematical perspective). However, I'm struggling to reconcile my knowledge with what it means to "fit" the linear regression model using least squares, as described above. What does it mean to "fit" something using least squares, as in the above example?

Comment: Informally, it just means that, given some data, we use a least squares algorithm to obtain estimates for the $\phi$. In general, when we say "fit" in the context of any statistical model, it means we just use some algorithm or procedure (in this case least squares) to estimate one or more coefficients. I will let the rigour police provide a more detailed answer :)

Comment: @RobertLong Ahh, ok; I think that algorithmic perspective is what I am missing in my conceptualisation. I only understand this from a mathematical perspective, so it isn't clear to me what they meant by "fitting" something "using least squares"; but if we consider that it is done using an algorithm (numerical methods), then that statement starts to make more sense!

Comment: What is your intended use of your current specified model or, are you first interested in getting a good model from the list of your variables pre-applications? Interested in producing forecasts, or just explaining historical oscillations?

Comment: @AJKOER This is just a question about theory. I am not trying to apply anything – just learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To “fit the model using least squares” means that we assume squared loss

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \sum_i ( y_i  - (\theta_0 + \sum_{m = 1}^M \theta_m z_{im}) )^2
$$

and we seek for minimum of it to find the estimates of the parameters

$$
\operatorname{arg\,min}_\theta \mathcal{L}(\theta)
$$

With linear regression, this can be done by applying linear algebra by [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), while for other models you would use some optimization algorithm to find the minimum.

“Fitting“ means “finding the parameters”. It’s “fitting” because we seek for such parameters that make the model “fit” the data best.

Comment: Tim: Welcome to the world of real applied statistics. Start by reading my answer!

Comment: @AJKOER You use "fit" in an unusual sense.  I believe most statisticians would describe your answer as a *modeling* exercise and would understand "fit" in the sense described here by Tim.  Virtually *nobody* would understand "fit" to mean stepwise regression!

Comment: Really, no one is acquainted with the expression "looking for the best fit", empirical analysis at its best especially with unexplainable variable and expected variables with the wrong signs. And, by the way, the reason one cannot forecast well with such empirically constructed models is that there is no strong underlying theoretical foundation for such models to continue to perform.  It is akin to forecasting via an interpolation polynomial based on all the data points. While the latter is good in some contexts, not always for accurate forecasting of turning points.

Comment: That might be true but the question is not about how to use the constructed model (e.g. for forecasting) and if it makes sense but simply about what "fit" means in terms of using least squares.

Comment: The question asked here speaks for itself. A novice has a list of variables and is wants to know how a least-square fit would proceeds. The likely correct answer is that a good fit may exist based on a subset of the variables. This would be accomplished using tools including stepwise regression which in the literature has been characterized as an empirical-based process. Claiming that the novice already has a precisely specified model and just requires only a completely theory consistent  based best-fit estimate is honestly not the case.

Comment: @AJKOER you are confusing training/fitting model with model selection. As a side-note, using stepwise selection is not the best method for model selection either.

Comment: Thanks PeteR.  Yes, estimating an interpolation is an answer. The proper course, however,  still would not be to assume categorically this is the case. The question needs clarification as to what the intent is to do with the fitted result.

Comment: Tim, I agree "stepwise selection is not the best method for model selection either" it was clearly presented as an example to develop a model.

Comment: Tim: training/fitting model is in the context/realm of machine learning. Here the question is how to explain/apply Least-Squares.

Comment: @AJKOER no; “fitting model using least squares” does not mean model selection. It means that you take a *particular* model and seek for best set of parameters, not that you compare different models.

Comment: As The Pointer has noted, he is learning. There is no real model, my comments therefore rationally apply to getting to a point where one has developed a model (that is, a suggested model based on the data and including its parameter estimation). I have mentioned some of the finer points along the learning curve relating to the eventual fitting of a least-squares regression model.  Some assert that only a numerical exercise is involved in 'fitting'  a LS model. My experience, this last step is usually trivial, not a source of angst in 'fitting' LS, but I only forecasted professionally.

Comment: @AJKOER ok, but your comments seem to imply that the things you describe mean “fitting the model” (the question), while they describe other procedures related to building models, what makes them misleading in terms of the question.

Answer (score -5):

Actually, assuming one is performing, at least, in part an exploratory model exercise, like involving specifying the best model form, possible explanatory variables, data transforms on those variables (to address normality and homogeneity of error variance, etc.) and even # of variables, a 'fitting' exercise, commonly occurs in stepwise least-squares context, for example. The latter process itself can be described in my, and the opinions of others, as a bit of an art, as opposed to pure science. In a reference article below employing the term empirical (whose [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empirical) includes "relying on experience or observation alone often without due regard for system and theory"), to quote:

> Stepwise methods are quite common to be reported in empirically based journal articles..

So, in my opinion, the connotation of the word 'fitting', as in a stepwise method relating to empirical-based work, is applicable, at times. There are, however, valid special cases, where one is just updating coefficients in a previously postulated and tested model. Also, in more recent times with access to algorithms to enable advanced numerical and statistical analysis (like PCA based regression analysis, factor regression, and this discussed in a 2016 article [Stepwise Regression and All Possible Subsets Regression in Education](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323705113_Stepwise_Regression_and_All_Possible_Subsets_Regression_in_Education)) developing good models with good explanatory variables is less of an art and more of a science.

I would also add in my opinion, however, that a knowledge background for the important aspect of specifying the best model form itself (not just relying on examination of goodness-of-fit metrics) is recommended to serve as a sound foundation in the appropriate context of physics, physical chemistry,..., as to why a proposed model form is, indeed, conceptually appropriate.

Comment: I am very thankful for the unexplained/unsourced downgrades for my qualifications on 'fitting' as I do want to set myself apart from others on this forum.

Comment: I believe you can find hint for the votes in whuber comment to your comment.